# Intel Pin with dependancies

Tags: c++, c, makefile, intel-pin

I am using Intel Pin to compile a C source and header file along with my c++ pintool. To do so I have added the following makefile rules in my makefile.rules file -

```
# Build the intermediate object file.
$(OBJDIR)testcpp$(OBJ_SUFFIX): testcpp.cpp
    $(CXX) $(TOOL_CXXFLAGS_NOOPT) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Build the intermediate object file.
$(OBJDIR)test$(OBJ_SUFFIX): test.c test.h
    $(CC) $(TOOL_CXXFLAGS) $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

# Build the tool as a dll (shared object).
$(OBJDIR)testcpp$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX): $(OBJDIR)test$(OBJ_SUFFIX) test.h
    $(LINKER) $(TOOL_LDFLAGS_NOOPT) $(LINK_EXE)$@ $(^:%.h=) $(TOOL_LPATHS) $(TOOL_LIBS)
```

testcpp.cpp is my pintool in C++ , test.c and test.h are my C source and header files.

I am using the rules mentioned in this link - https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97438/Pin/html/index.html#MAKEFILES

I removed this option from the file makefile.unix.config -

```
TOOL_CXXFLAGS_NOOPT += -fno-rtti
```

as this option is specifically for C++ and C does not use it. Since I am compiling both of them using the same compiler options, removing the option seemed better than adding a new rule for C and C++

I am able to make my program using the command "make". It generated a directory obj-intel64 with the object files test.o and testcpp.so, so my compiling worked fine.

For executing my program I use the following command -

```
$PIN_ROOT/pin -t obj-intel64/testcpp.so -- my_application_program
```

I get the following output -

```
E: Unable to load obj-intel64/testcpp.so
```

The file testcpp.so is present in the obj-intel64 directory, yet I am unable to load it. 
Any hints as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Pin tools don't support RTTI. This flag is required. I think you also end up compiling the test app into your tool (the example shows how to create a mixed c & cpp tool). I don't have access to the pin kit right now, but look at the make files in it to see how a test app should be built.

Comment: @nitzanms if I use that flag then I get the error that ‘-fno-rtti’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C.

Comment: This happens because you're using c++ build rules to compile a c file. Use the correct rules for .c files as documented in the makefile documentation.